# istio allowed incoming request from namespace which is not in allowed in authorization policy

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-security

I created an istio mesh setup as per [this guide](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/).

Now my goal is to only allow access to product page service from the same namespace default, not from another namespace.

so I created the below `AuthorizationPolicy`. If I apply only the first policy, it denies all requests very well from any namespace. But if you see the second policy, I only allowed the default namespace, still, it allowed access to product page service from another namespace.

Can you help me to find my configuration mistake?

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: productpage
 namespace: default
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: productpage
     version: v1
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: productpage-all
 namespace: default
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: productpage
     version: v1
 action: ALLOW
 rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        ports: ["9080"]
  - from:
    - source:
        namespaces: ["default"]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Option #1

Instead of creating `ALLOW` policy, you should explicitly `DENY` any traffic from namespaces other than *default*.

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
 name: productpage-all
 namespace: default
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: productpage
     version: v1
 action: DENY
 rules:
  - to:
    - operation:
        ports: ["9080"]
  - from:
    - source:
        notNamespaces: ["default"]
```

`DENY` policy takes precedence over `ALLOW` policy.

Create PeerAuthentication with `STRICT` mTLS mode:

---

#### Option #2

Optionally you could isolate *default* namespace with mTLS enabled

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: PeerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  mtls:
    mode: STRICT
```

Create `ALLOW` policy inside *default* namespace:

```yaml
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: namespace-isolation
  namespace: default
spec:
  action: ALLOW
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        namespaces: ["default"]
```

Comment: Still not worked. both namespace default and istio are mtls strict and injection enabled. I used below command to call productpage service from ubuntu pod in istio namespace.



kubectl exec -it -n istio  "$(kubectl get pod -n istio -l app=ubuntu -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')" -- curl -sS productpage.default.svc.cluster.local:9080/productpage | grep -o "<title>.*</title>"

Comment: I added second possible solution to the answer, see if it helps.

Comment: Appriciate your help!!. still does not work, might be your solution is correct but I'm missing something. I will upload all files to github from initial step minikube start, will see what happen. Thanks.